# jsonのデータからセレクトボックスの値を作成し、セレクト変更毎に表示させるデータを連動させたい

Tags: javascript, json

```js
var data = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "station":"SHIN AOMORI",
      "info":"青森県"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "station":"HACHINOHE",
      "info":"青森県"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "station":"AKITA",
      "info":"秋田県i"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "station":"MORIOKA",
      "info":"岩手県"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "station":"SHINJYO",
      "info":"山形県"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "station":"SENDAI",
      "info":"宮城県"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "station":"YAMAGATA",
      "info":"山形県"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "station":"FUKUSHIMA",
      "info":"福島県"
    }
  ]

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  for(var i in data) {
    $("#nameData").append("<option value=" +data[i].id + ">" + data[i].station +  "</option>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label">Destination</label>
<p class="control">
   <span class="select has-text-centered">
     <select id="nameData"></select>
  　</span>
</p>
<div id="info"></div>
```

上記のようなjsonオブジェクトを使い、動的にセレクトボックスを作成しましたが、
セレクトの`val()`と連動して`$('#info')`にjsonオブジェクトから同じidを持つinfoデータを表示させたいのですが、方法がわからず苦戦しています。
どなたかご教示頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

方法は他にもあると思いますが、
`.val()`であらかじめ設定されている`id`の番号が得られて、
`id`は配列の添字の＋１ですから`data[$(this).val()-1].info`で`info`が得られます。
それで、
`change`イベントで`info`のテキストを更新するようにします。
`change`イベントで変更するので、最初の値(info)についてはあらかじめ設定しておく必要があります。
以下コード

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  for(var i in data) {
    $("#nameData").append("<option value=" +data[i].id + ">" + data[i].station +  "</option>");
  }
  //追加のコード
  $("#nameData").change(function(){
    $("#info").text(data[$(this).val()-1].info);
  });
});
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXYさん
有難うございました。無事にこちらで実装ができました。

＞方法は他にもあると思いますが、
一度`$.getJSON`を使用などしてみたのですが、いまいち方法をつかめず、上記のように変更してみました。他にはどのような方法があったりするのでしょうか？後学のためにお伺いできると幸いです。

Comment: @kphex  `val()` で`value`として設定されている`id`を読んでいますが、`selectedIndex` で選択されている`option`の0始まりの番号が得られます。なので、`data[$(this).val()-1].info` は`data[this.selectedIndex].info` のようにも書けます。`id`がどうのではなく単に並びだけの問題。どっちにしろ同じ配列の位置だけを問題としているが、この場合`id`が飛び飛びでもＯＫ．

Comment: また、`id`をキーとするハッシュのようなＪＳＯＮデータにすることで、`id`で該当レコードを持ってくるようにもできます。